# split string based on 4 consecutive digit in it

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have `string s=A8GCB5913L6`. I want to split into three parts in shell. First part is all alphanumeric character up-to 4 consecutive digit, Second part is 4 consecutive digit and third part is remaining after 4 consecutive digit.

Example for above string:

1. `A8GCB`
2. `5913`
3. `L6`

I have tried `echo $s | grep -P '(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)'` but I can able to mark 4 digit in string, not able to copy.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question, do you want to only keep the matching 4 digits ? (in your example "5913"). In this case use the "-o" option of grep: "grep -Po ..."

Comment: I want three parts of the string in three different variable. Another thing is position of 4 consecutive digit anywhere in string. All the tree parts are required for post processing.

Comment: Can you provide more details to the first part? According "*First part is all alphanumeric character up-to 4 consecutive digit*", there should be four (4) digits, but there are five (5). Does it means the range of such digit is something like A-A[0-9]? Or would 1-9[A-Z]? Or an other pattern? So there could be 4-8 alphanumerical characters?

Comment: `grep -Po '^[A-Z0-9]+(?=[0-9]{4})'<<< "$s"`

Comment: CMOOTA5910M, AAGCC8257QU, A8GCB5913L6, A8GCB0951M. These are the patterns. I need all three parts of the string for post processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split using Perl, where the delimiter is 4 consecutive digits, keeping the delimiter.
Store the result in a bash array (calling it `pieces`).

```
pieces=(`echo $s | perl -ne 'for $piece (split /([0-9]{4})/) { print "$piece " }'`)
```

Now you can access the pieces using `${pieces[0]}`, `${pieces[1]}`, `${pieces[2]}`

Comment: The pure bash solution is undoubtedly better, I just find the `split` more readable than all of them being regex captures.

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
[[ "$s" =~ ^([0-9A-Z]+)([0-9]{4})(.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```

Output:

```
A8GCB 5913 L6
```

Comment: It is also possible to replace `^([0-9A-Z]+)([0-9]{4})(.*)` with `(.*)([0-9]{4})(.*)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the string and print the fragments, you can make use of Perl by saying:

```
#!/bin/bash

perl -ne '
    if (/(^[A-Z0-9]+)(?<![0-9])([0-9]{4})([A-Z0-9]+)/) {
        print "$1 $2 $3\n";
    }
' infile
```

where infile holds the strings:

```
A8GCB5913L6
CMOOTA5910M
AAGCC8257QU
A8GCB5913L6
A8GCB0951M
```

and the output yields:

```
A8GCB 5913 L6
CMOOTA 5910 M
AAGCC 8257 QU
A8GCB 5913 L6
A8GCB 0951 M
```

You can refer to $1, $2, and $3 for post processings.
Hope this helps.